# What is the correct HTTP response for requests without percent encoded URI?

Tags: api, http, http-response-codes, percent-encoding, uriencoding

Talking about HTTP API/HTTP Web server, what is the HTTP response code that the server should returns in case the client did not apply a URL encoding to requests params. I tried to look into HTTP RFCs but nothing specific or useful regarding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the request is invalid, you can return a 400 Bad Request status.

> **400 Bad Request**
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

([Source](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html))

If you want to send a more informative or specific response, you can provide additional details in the response body.